Printing Options can not be changed with Ubuntu 24.04
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 and my printer is an HP Deskjet 1010. Via settings/printer I click on "Printing Options" and change "Image Quality" from "Normal" to "Draft" and "Color" from "Color" to "Black Only Grayscale". There is no "Accept" or "Save" icon in the "Printing Options" box and when the box is closed the settings revert to "Normal" and "Draft". Even printing with the box still open these settings remain default.
How can I keep my desired printer settings?

Does your printer support "draft" mode? My 50+ years of experience in computing suggests that "draft" mode printing was a holdover from when one could save on printer costs by printing "draft" (lower quality). This is no longer the case.

Yes it does. I use the draft setting to save on ink usage.

is it possible that the printer was added via the IP address?
I noticed since the last GNOME update of ubuntu, I can not change any printer options added via IP address. However, when I remove the IP address added printers and re-ad them by selecting "Add Printer" and then choosing the printer needed to be added.
There will most likely be duplicates, simply do a print test page and rename the printer which works. Then you know Which one is which. After that, I was able to change the the printer options. (Still no "Ok" button, simply change and close)
Additionally, regarding the IP addresses. I tried chowning the printers.config file located at /etc/cups, changing the options from there, saving and rechowning root permissions, but still, didn't work.
Removing and re-adding in a different way, was the only thing that helped me.
Best of luck :)
